# How to assert Rest Client Exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I'm trying to assert the rest client exception. My piece of code is as follows:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public SomeResponse postMessage() {
        SomeBean requestObject = new SomeBean();
        SomeResponse response = null;
        try{
            response =  restTemaple.postForEntity("http://someUrl", requestObject, SomeResponse.class);
        } catch(RestTemplateException e) {
            Sysout("Rest Template Exception!");
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

My Test case is as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class testClass {

    @InjectMocks
    SomeClass service;

    @Mock
    RestTempalte restTemplate;

    @Test (expected = RestTemplateException.class)
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(
                restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SomeBean.class), Mockito.any()))
                .thenThrow(new RestClientException(null));

        service.postMessage();
        }

}
```

I'm getting a Junit assertion Error. Kindly find the stackTrace below:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Kindly me on this. How can i throw and assert the rest client exception here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're catching the exception into `postMessage` without rethrowing the exception. If you handle the exception into `postMessage`, you do not have to test if the method execution will throw a RestClientException , as it's handled there. If you wait for your method to throw this exception, do not catch it and simply use throws RestClientException in your method declaration

```
public class SomeClass {

    public void postMessage() throws RestClientException {
        SomeBean requestObject = new SomeBean();
        return restTemaple.postForEntity("http://someUrl", requestObject, SomeResponse.class);
    }

}
```

Then you do not call `postMessage` in your unit test. You're just giving the instruction to your mock on how to react when `RestTempalte.postForEntity` is called.

```
    @Test (expected = RestClientException.class)
        public void myTest() {
            Mockito.when(
                    restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SomeBean.class), Mockito.any()))
                    .thenThrow(new RestClientException(null));

            service.postMessage(); // something like that needed here
        }
```

It's also weird that you return something in `postMessage` as the return type of the method is `void`

```
public SomeResponse postMessage() throws RestClientException {
    SomeBean requestObject = new SomeBean();
    return restTemaple.postForEntity("http://someUrl", requestObject, SomeResponse.class);
}
```

Looks better

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the above code. I cannot avoid the catch block in above case as in catch blocks we are processing some server side logging logic. With the above code still getting the same stack trace.

Comment: So you need to review your test logic. If you catch this exception without rethrowing it, this assert will never match. If you do something in this catch block to handle the exception, you can test this behaviour. What kind of response this method returns when it goes through the catch block? In your example, it will return null. So you can test like that `//mockito stuff then you do -->    assertNull(service.postMessage());`

Comment: If you absolutely want to throw this exception keeping your logging logic, add the instruction `throw e;` at the end of your catch block, don't forget to add the `throws RestClientException` into your `postMessage` method declaration, as I said above

Comment: Thank you so much for your above help. I understand the above points. I have another scenario here like:

try{
 ...
 } catch(Exception e) {
  Throw new MyException();
}

and if i try to :

 Mockito.when(
                    restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(SomeBean.class), Mockito.any()))
                    .thenThrow(new MyException(null));

Its kinda throwing me an error like MockitoException expected.

any thoughts on this?

Comment: Because you cannot throw a custom exception for `restTemplate.postForEntity`. I've edited my answer as I saw that this method can throw a `RestClientException` not a `RestTemplateException`. If your method `postMessage` throws your `MyException` when a `RestClientException` is thrown by `restTemaple.postForEntity`, you have to specify it like that `.thenThrow(new RestClientException("a message"))` and `@Test (expected = MyException.class)`